# Character pointer created from Character not being assigned correct values

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is my code

```
     char * a() 
     {
        char * c;
        char b[10];
        b[0] = 'h';
        b[1] = 'i';
        b[2] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
            c[i] = b[i];

        return c;
    }

    int main() 
    {

        char * d;
        d = a();
        cout << d;
    }
```

The problem is no output is being shown when it should have shown hi. Just wanted to know why this error occured.

"Edit": I finally realise it was due to not initialising the pointers. Pointer should always be initialised .

```
Example char * c= new char;
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. The function scribbles over an uninitialized pointer and corrupts random memory. If your compiler issued a warning message, this is an example of why you should not ignore warning messages from your compiler, even if it still compiles the program. If your compiler produced no warning messages, perhaps you need a better C++ compiler.

Comment: I recieved no warning.I defined char *c in global and tried this code even then it didn't work.

Comment: I would just like to now how can i return a string element without using keyword string and store it in a char * where the returning function has been called.

Comment: "I received no warnings" - then you need to turn up your warning levels and treat them as errors. [See it live here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74e89508e26ab100)

Comment: hi guys can you please upvote this answer now as the question in itself was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want an array you need to allocate space for the items. Just a pointer is not enough. Something like

```
char* c= new char[10]; //room for 10 chars
```

and be sure not to try indexes greater than 10-1=9. Accesing `c[10]` is undefined behaviour.

You can return that pointer (`return c;`). But don't forget to free the allocated memory when it isn't needed any more

```
d = a();
cout << d;
delete [] d; //free memory allocated with new d[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of errors in your program. Look that you create pointer of type char and then you do something like this:
c[i]
which will cause error. This is not what you want to do.
Also
you should not return pointer/reference to local variables. Local variables are destroyed when they leave scope (in your example b is destroyed at "return c;").
So when you create pointer to local object (notice that your variables are created on stack, not on heap) and return from function your pointer points to memory which is destroyed. It may worked it may not (undefined behaviour) but you should never do something like that.

Comment: i defined char b[10] in global so that it does not get destroyed. Even then it did not work.

Comment: I would just like to now how can i return a string element without using keyword string and store it in a char * where the returning function has been called.

Comment: "String element" is a letter or sign right? Like "a" ? Or you want to return let's say
"something" but not as string but char pointer to the beggining?

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve?
https://ideone.com/RPgR8G

Of course this is not best solution but I want to make sure we are on the same page. (i.e if you are using c++ >= 11 you should avoid using ovning pointers (created using new)), use smart pointers instead!.
And in your example returning just std::string would do the work.
There is something called SSO (Small String Optimization) which will cause your code to be more efficient. Trust your compiler:D

Comment: hi guys can you please upvote this answer now as the question in itself was correct